# SSH on Raspberry Pi3

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, ssh

I install "ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64" and "qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.8.0" on on my laptop.
I wrote an application with Qt 5.8 for windows. It works fine in windows and Ubuntu.
IP address of raspberry ("hostname -I"): 169.254.181.63
Enable SSH:
In raspberry: from Preferences menu of Rasbian.
In Ubuntu:

```
sudo service ssh status
.... 
.... Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
.... Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
.... Server listening on :: port 22.
.... Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

I connect raspberry pi to laptop with Ethernet cable.
I create new device (Generic Linux Device) in "Tools -> Options…-> Devices tab"
Host name: 169.254.181.63
SSH port:22
Username: pi
Password: 1 (set by me)
Result test:

```
Device test: SSH connection: Network unreachable.
```

In Ubuntu:

```
ssh  pi@169.254.181.63
ssh: connect to host 169.254.181.63 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

I edit the interface file to set the network configuration in raspberry:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

**Update:**

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.100.100
netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
```

**Update:**
But after reboot raspberry and execute "hostname -I", I have "192.168.100.100 169.254.181.63"

Comment: you defined your network as `192.168.100.0` -> class C -> so your IP should be set to `192.168.100.100`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure a static IP in this way (see this [link](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialNetworking.html)):

```
  auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.100.100
   network 192.168.100.0
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   broadcast 192.168.200.25
```

You've to move `address`, `netmask`, etc. below the line `iface eth0 inet static`.

Comment: I change and after reboot raspberry and execute "hostname -I", I have "192.168.100.100 169.254.181.63"

Answer (score 0):

Check if your correct IP address is correct and use command in terminal. Open the terminal use this command and find the exact ip address:

```
cd /var/misc
cat misc
```

Copy this IP address and use this command:

```
ssh pi@ip_address
```

Answer (score -1):

change the order. put the settings under iface eth0 not the lo.

```
iface eth0 inet manual
  address 192.168.200.100
  network 192.168.100.0
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  broadcast 192.168.200.25
```